# Про работу PHP функции ignore_user_abort

Tags: php

С помощью функции ignore_user_abort, можно сделать так, чтобы код работал вне зависимости от соединения пользователя.
То есть, код работает практически без интернета? Я попробовал выключить интернет, и код все равно сработал. Как это понимать? Так же можно написать целую программу, которая работает без интернета (я имею ввиду без моего интернета, то есть практически БЕСПЛАТНО), я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, вы совершенно не так поняли) Возможно вы сталкивались с двумя частыми состояниями выполнения php скриптов.

1) Hello World - Программа сработала, отдала в браузер ответ, все хорошо)

2) `"Demon"` - Сложная операция которая долго не отдает ответ, это значит что, что то под капотом крутится, чаще всего это какие то внешние запросы, работа с файлами, бесконечные циклы и тд. (в общем сложные операции, требующие время)

Ну так вот. Когда вы закрываете вкладку, вы можете указать как будет работать ваш скрипт.

1) при потере соединения скрипт умрет 2) продолжит работать

В примере на php.net указан пример как создать [демон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0))

PS Интернет нужен если вы обращаетесь к внешнему серверу где крутится ваш php

Comment: При обращении нужен, но для дальнейшей работы разве нужен? Я написал код, который отправляет запрос к другому урл, а последний создает 1 файл. Включил скрипт и выключил интернет, и все сработало.

Comment: @Miqayel потому что интернет нужен серверу) а его как я понимаю вы не отключили. Без интернета вы не отправите запрос на удаленный сервер

Comment: То есть мой интернет только отправляет запрос, а весь бек-энд код работает через интернет сервера? Всегда так?

Comment: @Miqayel Давайте я вам объясню чуть по другому) например вы хотите что бы в локальной сети был сервер, а все его члены смогли отправлять на него запрос. Ну так вот, при подключении к Интернету, вы уже в такой сети, каждый может достучаться до каждого, конечно количество узлов между ними может быть значительно, но это все равно быстро. Я это о том, что сервер у вас может быть локальный и в интернете (чей то чужой сервер, до которого вы можете достучаться) Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос

Comment: @Miqayel я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Для бэкенд работы нужен интернет или нет?